# How to create an summary page from multiple sources with a static index

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a very simple sheet containing a column composed of rangers from other sheets, and a column with a string that will be used as an index. So for example, If I had these columns on 3 different sheets:

```
Meat        Veggie        Cheese
----        ------        ------
Chicken     Onion         Mozarella
Ham         Peppers       Cheddar
Beef        Tomato        Brie
Chicken
```

And I want to make a table that looks like the following:

```
Toppings        
--------

A              B
---            ---
Chicken        top-01
Ham            top-02
Beef           top-03
Onion          top-04
Peppers        top-05
Tomato         top-06
Mozzarella     top-07
Cheddar        top-08
Brie           top-09
```

I have basically achieved this by using the following formula for column A, and auto-filling column B.

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE({meat!A:A;veggie!A:A;cheese!A:A}), NOT(ISBLANK(UNIQUE({meat!A:A;veggie!A:A;cheese!A:A}))))
```

This is all fine, BUT there's a possibility that further toppings could be added in the future, and this is where my problem lies. If I now add toppings to an individual sheet, I want the codes in column B to remain static. So for example if I update my veggie sheet to:

```
Veggie
------
Onion
Peppers
Tomato
Olives
```

My toppings sheet will update to

```
Toppings        
--------

A              B
---            ---
Chicken        top-01
Ham            top-02
Beef           top-03
Onion          top-04
Peppers        top-05
Tomato         top-06
Olives         top-07
Mozzarella     top-08
Cheddar        top-09
Brie
```

In this scenario, I would prefer to add a code later, and also preserve the order the ranges are obtained, but I absolutely cannot have the codes for each topping change here. As such my desired output in this case would be:

```
Toppings        
--------

A              B
---            ---
Chicken        top-01
Ham            top-02
Beef           top-03
Onion          top-04
Peppers        top-05
Tomato         top-06
Olives
Mozzarella     top-07
Cheddar        top-08
Brie           top-09
```

How would this be achieved?

Comment: Have you looked into Google Apps Script?

Comment: I did consider that, but was hoping there was a simpler solution!

Comment: I think you should make a benchmark static list of your initially filtered results mapped with your initial assignment of column b values. Essentially making a static map of key -> value pairs. Add new keys only if they don't exist already, and use a placeholder for the value. You don't want to combine a dynamic uncontrolled list of keys with a static list of values.

Comment: Did you advance with this?

Comment: @Aerials I did not. I take your point about not wanting to combine dynamic lists with static values though. On hindsight maybe it's just not possible because it's a poorly formed concept